# Understanding method calls in interfaces and predefined classes

Tags: java, android

Like  BaseExpandableListAdapter.java class in android there are various other classes and interface I want to understand in which sequence different methods are called in these predefined classes and interfaces , in android developers site only method description is given, i want to know how individual methods are called and how there returned values are used.One way to do is ,to write log statements everywhere and check which occurs where  i don't want to do it ,  is there any book or other means from where i can understand the flow.

Comment: Search online, maybe someone has done this exploration themself for the class you are interested in. Otherwise, you'll have to do it yourself the way you just described.

Comment: thanks but , i want a more general solution , there are various options in android studio like view hierarchy , find declarations, find usages  ,like these are there any options to find which method calls which method in work flow.?

Comment: Not unless they are documented as such. Unless someone else has already done so, all you can do is experiment and/or read source code. That's just the way it is.